# Segmentation fault, while calling QOpenGLShaderProgram::link() in OpenGL driver?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

Currently, I am trying to implement a compute shader. For that, I am using a template, which uses Qt to handle the OpenGL stuff. To create compute shaders this function is used, which works well for some other compute shaders:

```
std::shared_ptr<QOpenGLShaderProgram> createComputeShaderProgram(const QString &computeShaderPath)
{
  auto shaderProgram = std::make_shared<QOpenGLShaderProgram>();
  bool result;
  //! Load and compile the compute shader
  if (!computeShaderPath.isEmpty()) {
    result = shaderProgram->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Compute, computeShaderPath);
    if (!result) {
        qWarning() << computeShaderPath;
        qWarning() << shaderProgram->log();
    }
  }
  //! ...and finally link it to resolve any references.
  result = shaderProgram->link();
  if (!result)
    qWarning() << "Could not link shader program:" << shaderProgram->log();
  return shaderProgram;
}
```

As I said, this works well for every other compute shader. The problem occurs while calling the line

```
result = shaderProgram->link();
```

I did not change big stuff within the shader which causes the error. I just added a basic naiv neighbor search. To figure out, when the error occurs I tried to comment some lines out and see if it's compiling now. From that, I got the information the error occurs because of the two lines marked with `//relevant line` from the following shader function:

```
#define NUM_NEIGHBORS 4

float distNN[NUM_NEIGHBORS];
int idxNN[NUM_NEIGHBORS];

void neighborSearch()
{
  vec3 currentPosition = /* ... calc the current position with the compute shader invocation ID */;
  vec3 currentPoint = vec3(0.0);
  float curDist = 0.0;

  currentPoint = pointCloud[0].vertex.xyz;
  curDist = distance(currentPosition, currentPoint);
  float maxDist = curDist;
  int idxMaxDist = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < NUM_NEIGHBORS; i++)
  {
    currentPoint = pointCloud[i].vertex.xyz;
    curDist = distance(currentPosition, currentPoint);
    if(curDist >= maxDist)
    {
        maxDist = curDist;   //relevant line
        idxMaxDist = i;      //relevant line
    }
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_NEIGHBORS; i++)
  {
    distNN[i] = maxDist;
    idxNN[i] = idxMaxDist;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < nmbPoints; i++)
  {
    currentPoint = pointCloud[i].vertex.xyz;
    curDist = distance(currentPoint,currentPosition);
    if(curDist < distNN[NUM_NEIGHBORS-1])
    {
        bool inserted = false;
        int j = NUM_NEIGHBORS - 2;
        while(!inserted)
        {
            if(curDist < distNN[j] && j >= 0)
            {
                j--;
            }
            else
            {
                for(int k = NUM_NEIGHBORS-1; k > j+1; k--)
                {
                    distNN[k] = distNN[k-1];
                    idxNN[k] = idxNN[k-1];
                }
                distNN[j+1] = curDist;
                idxNN[j+1] = i;
                inserted = true;
            }
        }
    }//curDist < NUM_NEIGHBORS-1
  }//iterate over all neighbors
}//neighborSearch()
```

I hope that I did not remove something crucial for this, while simplifying this shader. I compiled it with an address sanitizer to and the output of it is:

```
==5365== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00000000002c (pc 0x7fde1d61b630 sp 0x7fffb34c61b8 bp 0x7fffb34c77a0 T0)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
#0 0x7fde1d61b62f (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xb5062f)
#1 0x7fde1d4eacc5 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa1fcc5)
#2 0x7fde1d4eb25e (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa2025e)
#3 0x7fde1d4eb34f (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa2034f)
#4 0x7fde1d4f051f (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa2551f)
#5 0x7fde1d4f1b43 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa26b43)
#6 0x7fde1d4f04f7 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa254f7)
#7 0x7fde1d4f0d83 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa25d83)
#8 0x7fde1d4f10f6 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa260f6)
#9 0x7fde1d4cce43 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa01e43)
#10 0x7fde1d4d2bd4 (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa07bd4)
#11 0x7fde1d4d325a (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0xa0825a)
#12 0x7fde1dc616ad (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0x11966ad)
#13 0x7fde1dc6741b (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0x119c41b)
#14 0x7fde1dc44a7a (/usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49+0x1179a7a)
#15 0x7fde22c7eca0 (/QT_DIRECTORY/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1+0x34dca0)
#16-24 some project relevant stuff
==5365== ABORTING
```

Does anybody knows why this problem occurs and how to solve it? I have really no idea what to do now.

system information:

- 64bit OpenSuse 13.1
- Nvidia GT 555M
- running the program directly from `optirun qtcreator`

Valgrind output:

```
$ optirun valgrind --leak-check=yes ./projectname
==4038== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4038== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4038== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4038== Command: ./projectname
==4038== 
==4038== Shadow memory range interleaves with an existing memory mapping. ASan cannot proceed correctly. ABORTING.
==4038== Process memory map follows:
    0x000000400000-0x00000055f000   PROJECT_DIRECTORY/projectname
    0x00000075e000-0x000000766000   PROJECT_DIRECTORY/projectname
    0x000000766000-0x00000076d000   PROJECT_DIRECTORY/projectname
    0x00000076d000-0x00000076e000
    0x000004000000-0x000004020000   /lib64/ld-2.18.so
    0x000004020000-0x00000402d000
    0x000004035000-0x00000403d000
    0x000004052000-0x000004062000
    0x00000421f000-0x000004220000   /lib64/ld-2.18.so
    0x000004220000-0x000004221000   /lib64/ld-2.18.so
    0x000004221000-0x000004222000
    0x000004222000-0x000004223000
    0x000004a22000-0x000004a23000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004a23000-0x000004c22000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004c22000-0x000004c23000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004c23000-0x000004c24000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004c24000-0x000004c32000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004c32000-0x000004e32000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004e32000-0x000004e33000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004e33000-0x000004e34000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
    0x000004e34000-0x000004e35000   /usr/lib64/libdlfaker.so
    0x000004e35000-0x000005035000   /usr/lib64/libdlfaker.so
    0x000005035000-0x000005036000   /usr/lib64/libdlfaker.so
    0x000005036000-0x000005037000   /usr/lib64/libdlfaker.so
    0x000005037000-0x000005104000   /usr/lib64/librrfaker.so
    0x000005104000-0x000005304000   /usr/lib64/librrfaker.so
    0x000005304000-0x000005307000   /usr/lib64/librrfaker.so
    0x000005307000-0x000005309000   /usr/lib64/librrfaker.so
    0x000005309000-0x00000534c000
    0x00000534c000-0x000005375000   /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0
    0x000005375000-0x000005574000   /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0
    0x000005574000-0x000005575000   /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0
    0x000005575000-0x000005576000   /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0
    0x000005576000-0x0000082db000
    0x0000082db000-0x000008358000   /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
    0x000008358000-0x000008557000   /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
    0x000008557000-0x000008559000   /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
    0x000008559000-0x00000855a000   /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1.3.1
    0x00000855a000-0x0000085bb000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2.1
    0x0000085bb000-0x0000087ba000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2.1
    0x0000087ba000-0x0000087bc000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2.1
    0x0000087bc000-0x0000087be000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2.1
    0x0000087be000-0x000008db9000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.2.1
    0x000008db9000-0x000008fb9000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.2.1
    0x000008fb9000-0x000008fe3000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.2.1
    0x000008fe3000-0x000009004000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.2.1
    0x000009004000-0x000009464000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1
    0x000009464000-0x000009663000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1
    0x000009663000-0x000009677000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1
    0x000009677000-0x000009689000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.2.1
    0x000009689000-0x00000968a000
    0x00000968a000-0x000009b33000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1
    0x000009b33000-0x000009d33000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1
    0x000009d33000-0x000009d3d000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1
    0x000009d3d000-0x000009d56000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1
    0x000009d56000-0x000009d58000
    0x000009d58000-0x000009e35000   /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.331.49
    0x000009e35000-0x00000a034000   /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.331.49
    0x00000a034000-0x00000a074000   /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.331.49
    0x00000a074000-0x00000a08b000
    0x00000a08b000-0x00000a0a3000   /lib64/libpthread-2.18.so
    0x00000a0a3000-0x00000a2a3000   /lib64/libpthread-2.18.so
    0x00000a2a3000-0x00000a2a4000   /lib64/libpthread-2.18.so
    0x00000a2a4000-0x00000a2a5000   /lib64/libpthread-2.18.so
    0x00000a2a5000-0x00000a2a9000
    0x00000a2a9000-0x00000a393000   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    0x00000a393000-0x00000a592000   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    0x00000a592000-0x00000a59a000   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    0x00000a59a000-0x00000a59c000   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    0x00000a59c000-0x00000a5b1000
    0x00000a5b1000-0x00000a6b3000   /lib64/libm-2.18.so
    0x00000a6b3000-0x00000a8b2000   /lib64/libm-2.18.so
    0x00000a8b2000-0x00000a8b3000   /lib64/libm-2.18.so
    0x00000a8b3000-0x00000a8b4000   /lib64/libm-2.18.so
    0x00000a8b4000-0x00000a8c2000   /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
    0x00000a8c2000-0x00000aac1000   /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
    0x00000aac1000-0x00000aac2000   /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
    0x00000aac2000-0x00000aac3000   /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0
    0x00000aac3000-0x00000aad9000   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x00000aad9000-0x00000acd8000   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x00000acd8000-0x00000acd9000   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x00000acd9000-0x00000acda000   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
    0x00000acda000-0x00000ae7e000   /lib64/libc-2.18.so
    0x00000ae7e000-0x00000b07e000   /lib64/libc-2.18.so
    0x00000b07e000-0x00000b082000   /lib64/libc-2.18.so
    0x00000b082000-0x00000b084000   /lib64/libc-2.18.so
    0x00000b084000-0x00000b088000
    0x00000b088000-0x00000b08b000   /lib64/libdl-2.18.so
    0x00000b08b000-0x00000b28a000   /lib64/libdl-2.18.so
    0x00000b28a000-0x00000b28b000   /lib64/libdl-2.18.so
    0x00000b28b000-0x00000b28c000   /lib64/libdl-2.18.so
    0x00000b28c000-0x00000b290000   /usr/lib64/libXv.so.1.0.0
    0x00000b290000-0x00000b48f000   /usr/lib64/libXv.so.1.0.0
    0x00000b48f000-0x00000b490000   /usr/lib64/libXv.so.1.0.0
    0x00000b490000-0x00000b491000   /usr/lib64/libXv.so.1.0.0
    0x00000b491000-0x00000b5c9000   /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
    0x00000b5c9000-0x00000b7c9000   /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
    0x00000b7c9000-0x00000b7ca000   /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
    0x00000b7ca000-0x00000b7cf000   /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0
    0x00000b7cf000-0x00000b7e0000   /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
    0x00000b7e0000-0x00000b9df000   /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
    0x00000b9df000-0x00000b9e0000   /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
    0x00000b9e0000-0x00000b9e1000   /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0
    0x00000b9e1000-0x00000ba30000   /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000ba30000-0x00000bc30000   /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bc30000-0x00000bc31000   /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bc31000-0x00000bc32000   /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bc32000-0x00000bd33000   /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bd33000-0x00000bf32000   /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bf32000-0x00000bf33000   /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bf33000-0x00000bf34000   /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000bf34000-0x00000bf35000
    0x00000bf35000-0x00000c13e000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.51.1
    0x00000c13e000-0x00000c33e000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.51.1
    0x00000c33e000-0x00000c34b000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.51.1
    0x00000c34b000-0x00000c34d000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.51.1
    0x00000c34d000-0x00000c34e000
    0x00000c34e000-0x00000c4be000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.51.1
    0x00000c4be000-0x00000c6bd000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.51.1
    0x00000c6bd000-0x00000c6ce000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.51.1
    0x00000c6ce000-0x00000c6cf000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.51.1
    0x00000c6cf000-0x00000c6d4000
    0x00000c6d4000-0x00000c6d5000   /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000c6d5000-0x00000c8d4000   /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000c8d4000-0x00000c8d5000   /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000c8d5000-0x00000c8d6000   /usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0.3800.2
    0x00000c8d6000-0x00000c8dd000   /lib64/librt-2.18.so
    0x00000c8dd000-0x00000cadc000   /lib64/librt-2.18.so
    0x00000cadc000-0x00000cadd000   /lib64/librt-2.18.so
    0x00000cadd000-0x00000cade000   /lib64/librt-2.18.so
    0x00000cade000-0x00000cae1000   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-tls.so.331.49
    0x00000cae1000-0x00000cce0000   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-tls.so.331.49
    0x00000cce0000-0x00000cce1000   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-tls.so.331.49
    0x00000cce1000-0x00000e849000   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49
    0x00000e849000-0x00000ea48000   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49
    0x00000ea48000-0x00000f4d3000   /usr/lib64/libnvidia-glcore.so.331.49
    0x00000f4d3000-0x00000f4f0000
    0x00000f4f0000-0x00000f50e000   /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
    0x00000f50e000-0x00000f70d000   /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
    0x00000f70d000-0x00000f70e000   /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
    0x00000f70e000-0x00000f70f000   /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0
    0x00000f70f000-0x00000f716000   /usr/lib64/libffi.so.4.0.1
    0x00000f716000-0x00000f915000   /usr/lib64/libffi.so.4.0.1
    0x00000f915000-0x00000f916000   /usr/lib64/libffi.so.4.0.1
    0x00000f916000-0x00000f917000   /usr/lib64/libffi.so.4.0.1
    0x00000f917000-0x00000f982000   /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.5
    0x00000f982000-0x00000fb82000   /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.5
    0x00000fb82000-0x00000fb83000   /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.5
    0x00000fb83000-0x00000fb84000   /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.5
    0x00000fb84000-0x0000110cc000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.51.1
    0x0000110cc000-0x0000112cc000   QT_DIRECTORYgcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.51.1
    0x0000112cc000-0x0000112cd000   QT_DIRECTORY/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.51.1
    0x0000112cd000-0x0000112d0000   /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
    0x0000112d0000-0x0000114cf000   /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
    0x0000114cf000-0x0000114d0000   /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
    0x0000114d0000-0x0000114d1000   /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0
    0x000038000000-0x0000383d6000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
    0x0000385d5000-0x0000385d9000   /usr/local/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
    0x0000385d9000-0x00003a048000
    0x000802001000-0x000802b9c000
    0x000802b9c000-0x000802b9e000
    0x000802b9e000-0x000802c9e000   [stack:4038]
    0x000802c9e000-0x000802ca0000
    0x000802ca0000-0x000802ca1000   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-4038-by-USERNAME-on-linux-92w9.site
    0x000802ca1000-0x000802cbd000
    0x000802cbd000-0x000803359000
    0x00080339b000-0x000803a94000
    0x000803b6c000-0x000806434000
    0x000ffeffe000-0x000fff001000
    0x7ffd84e0f000-0x7ffd84e31000
    0xffffffffff600000-0xffffffffff601000   [vsyscall]
==4038== End of process memory map.
==4038== 
==4038== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4038==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4038==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==4038== 
==4038== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4038== 
==4038== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4038== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

output of `optirun valgrind -v ./projectname` is online [here](http://pastebin.com/SYcvpmdR)

glslangValidator output:

```
Warning, version 430 is not yet complete; most version-specific features are present, but some are missing.
```

quick fix:

Adding the line `i = i+1-1;` right before the relevant lines resolves the error.

Comment: Does valgrind say anything about *your* program or Qt?

Comment: I added the output information. Do you need anymore?

Comment: Well... that doesn't say much. I would've expected the log to report information about the crash, as well as possible memory errors (which, if coming from your code or from Qt, would indicate a problem there to be fixed).

Comment: I am new to valgrind, can you give me a hint how to get these information?

Comment: What if you just run `valgrind -v yourapp` ?

Comment: I added the output to the question and pposted it [here](http://www.pastebin.ca/3117259). Is that the information you are looking for?

Comment: `==7569== Shadow memory range interleaves with an existing memory mapping. ASan cannot proceed correctly. ABORTING.` can you please disable ASan totally and retry? That interferes with valgrind and might cause your crash in the first place.

Comment: Okay. New one is up [here](http://pastebin.com/SYcvpmdR)

Comment: Smells like driver bug. Try updating them.

Comment: okay. A driver update solved the problem. But, as it was boud to happen, now it can not compile the shader because of the three defines Qt is adding at the top of the shader and the driver wants to have #version ... as the first line. -.-

Comment: Nah. I am sorry for the wrong information. The driver update did not help. Now, it additionally causes an error, when #version ... is not at the top of the shader, without any space or comments in front of it. This bug seems to be solved with Qt version 5.5

Comment: Put the #version as the first line and leave a couple of empty lines?

Comment: Yes, that works. I already tried it. But the segmenation fault error  still exists.